# MVC dynamic validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I get a requirement like this:

Different airlines require different traveller's information.

For example:
Airline A , need ID Number ,child birthday is required and age must between 2 ~ 12.

Airline B , need ID Number and gender.

Airline C, require all travellers' birthday, and child age must between 2 ~12.

etc...

My question is : Is there anyway in different scenarios use different validation rules ?
In addition , all children and adult's information collect in one page, so I need specify validation rule for instance of traveller.

How can I do it in **MVC** ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use IValidateObject in mvc. you have not specified what you have done till now but i would have created an Airline viewmodel and validate it somewhat like this

```
public class AirlineViewModel: IValidatableObject 
{   
public string AirlineName{ get; set; }

public int IDNo{ get; set; }  

 //  your other properties here  

public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    List<ValidationResult> err = new List<ValidationResult>();
    if(AirlineName.Equals("Airline a"))
    {
       if(IDNo>0)
       {
          yield return new ValidationResult("ID cannot be empty", new[] { "IDNo" });
       }
    }
    else if(AirlineName.Equals("Airline b"))
    {
        //  your stuff here
    }
    else if(AirlineName.Equals("Airline C"))
    {
        //  your stuff here
    }           
}
```

}

Comment: Be aware that IValidatableObject does not support client-side validation.

Answer (score 1):

As mazhar mentioned, IValidateableObject is one option if you don't care about client-side validation.  Another option creating your own data annotation attributes.  A third option is to use a third party validation library like Fluent Validation.